# Windows 10 folders showing up in "Music" only in File Explorer

Tags: windows, command-line, windows-explorer

I have Windows 10, have been doing updates right along, it's currently at 10.0.18363.

I created a "files" folder as a "Windows Library" that I use to store personal things; below that are folders such as "backups", "programming", etc. Yesterday I noticed a "programming" folder in the "**Music**" library folder, and wondered if I'd accidentally copied or moved it.

On investigation, I discovered that all of the folders from my "files" library also appear in the "Music" library, but only in File Explorer. If I open a DOS command window and look for them with the DIR command, they are not there. These folders do not appear in other libraries, e.g., "Videos".

I am somewhat familiar with "Junction Points" on Windows; if I use DOS and enter "DIR /AL" in the files and Music folders, I get no junction points listed. If I enter "DIR /AH" it shows desktop.ini in Music and nothing in files, so there are no hidden folders in either place.

I can rename one of the folders in either folder, and the renaming immediately shows up in the other folder; that tells me that the ones appearing in the "Music" library are actually the same folders as in the "files" library.

I searched for solutions via Google and found things that did not seem to apply. I followed one suggestion to turn off entries for "Recent" and "Frequently Used" files/folders in Quick Access, but that had no effect on these folders. I do not have any "cloud storage" enabled or in use for the machine, and I've never completed installation of OneDrive (i.e., I've never given it my email address). I do not have a Microsoft account.

Does anyone have ideas about why these are showing up, and how I can get rid of them?

EDIT: someone wanted screenshots; here are the File Explorer listings, showing 'cars' in both places:

[image: File Explorer listings]

And here's what I see in DOS:

[image: DOS listings]

EDIT2:

Here's a screenshot of a one-window File Explorer instance, showing that the Music library has something else in it named 'Music' (another library? I cannot tell) and something else in it named 'files'. Still hpping for an explanation.

[image: One-window File Explorer version]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

True **Libraries** are *virtual* folders that present aggregate views of the contents of one or more file system folders(directories). The **Properties** dialog for a Library differs from that of its source folder(s):

[image]

[image]

You've most likely accidentally added the same folder to multiple Library definitions. Check the **Properties** dialog of both Libraires side-by-side.